# "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"

Tags: machine-learning, rstudio, h2o, h2o4gpu

I can't get the h2o to work in my R. It shows the following error. Have no clue what it means. Previously it gave me an error because I didn't have Java 64 bit version. I downloaded the 64bit - restarted my pc - and started the process again and now it gives me this error.

Any suggestions?

```
> library(h2o) 
>h2o.init()



    `H2O is not running yet, starting it now.`..

        Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
            C:\Users\E0475878\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpieqnRc/h2o_E0475878_started_from_r.out


C:\Users\E0475878\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpieqnRc/h2o_E0475878_started_from_r.err

    java version "1.6.0_26"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

    Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................ 
    [1] "localhost"
    [1] 54321
    [1] TRUE
    [1] -1
    **[1] "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"**
    [1] 127
    **

    Error in h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321) : 
      H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
    In addition: Warning message:
    running command 'curl 'http://localhost:54321'' had status 127

**
```

Please advice

Comment: Maybe simply you don't have this port opened?

Answer (score 1):

> java version "1.6.0_26"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)

H2O requires Java 7 or later (noted [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html)).  You are using Java 6.  You will need to upgrade Java. If you can, uninstall Java 6 and install Java 7 or 8.